# About career break in CV

Tags: career-path, postdocs, cv, time-off

I am going to apply for a postdoc position and there is an item about career break. 
Having finished my Master degree, I got a position titles Director of Research in a College for about 6 years. In the meanwhile, I was visiting lecturer for some courses for different academic levels such as sub-bachelor, Bachelor students. After that experience I was involved in a research project as an assistant professor, then after 6 months  I commenced my Ph.D studies. I do not know whether the years before stating Ph.D ( 6 years as lecturer and director of research) is career break or not?

Comment: Do you mind rephrasing the question, it's a bit unclear at the moment (at least to me). Also what is a sub-bachelor student?

Comment: Subbachelor is an associative degree awarded to students who intend to find a job as technisian after completing their studies. I edited the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect that the intent of the question is to have you explain things that you did completely unrelated to your career and to your field. As such, the things you describe don't seem to qualify. I don't think they are *necessarily* asking about breaks in your academic progress (time between degrees), but they might be interested in that.

But the sorts of things you did prior to the doctorate would seem, to me, to be supportive of your case for the position and so should be mentioned *somehow* in your CV whether in this "section" or just in a narrative.

Some people need to take a *career break* to care for an ailing parent or child, for example, or because they are in jail (oops). In such breaks it may be impossible to do much professionally. Those need to be explained if they last more than a few months.

Comment: Totally. I'm on a "career break" because I am on parental leave right now. Nothing you describe is a career break. Indeed, time between master's and PhD is unlikely to be considered a "career break" no matter what happened in that time. In a way, your academic career starts post-PhD. However as @Buffy says, certainly mention those things on your CV, they sound very positive.